# Python issues with pandas.apply, looking for suggestions for alternatives or help to fix issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying to fix a little error in my data but I am having troubles doing this.

I have a sample df that looks like this:

```
       Date Ticker Type  Quantity
0  20200501   AAPL   SS       200
1  20200502   AAPL    B       150
2  20200502   APPL    B       100
3  20200502   APPL    B        50
4  20200502   AAPL    S       100
```

In this scenario I shorted 200 shares of apple on may 1st, then covered them on may second and bought & sold 100 shares more the same day. The transactions shown however show that after I covered 150 shares of my 200 shares, i first bought 100 before covering the other 50. this is not possible, so these rows are flipped. Instead of flipping the right rows however, I would like to change the values in the 'Type' column of my buy to cover orders from 'B' to 'BC'. so the desired output is:

```
       Date Ticker Type  Quantity
0  20200501   AAPL   SS       200
1  20200502   AAPL   BC       150
2  20200502   APPL    B       100
3  20200502   APPL   BC        50
4  20200502   AAPL    S       100
```

While trying to accomplish this, I was creating a function with pd.apply that calculates the current position size to check whether the quantity column exceeds the size column, and if so it should change the 'Type' column. Apparently though, .apply does not update the dataframe that its working with (atleast to my understanding), so when I tried to calculate position sizes i stumbled upon a problem.

(example of problem):

```
      Date Ticker Type  Quantity  PositionSize
0  20200501   AAPL   SS       200        -200.0
1  20200502   AAPL    B       150           NaN
2  20200502   APPL    B       100           NaN
Current position Size -200.0
Quantity to update 50
```

I was hoping someone on here could help me out to fix my issue or give me a better alternative for .apply in this case.

sample of code im using for this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [20200501, 20200502, 20200502, 20200502, 20200502],
                'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'APPL', 'APPL', 'AAPL'],
                'Type': ['SS', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'S'],
                'Quantity': [200, 150, 200, 50, 100]})

print(df1)

if df1.loc[0, 'Type'] == 'B':
    df1.loc[0, 'PositionSize'] = df1.loc[0, 'Quantity']
elif df1.loc[0, 'Type'] == 'BC':
    df1.loc[0, 'PositionSize'] = df1.loc[0, 'Quantity']
else:
    df1.loc[0, 'PositionSize'] = -df1.loc[0, 'Quantity']

def Check_Type(row):
    if row.name is not 0:
        f_df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
        f_df1 = f_df1[f_df1.index < row.name]
        s = f_df1['PositionSize'].sum()
        if row.Type == 'B':
            q = row.Quantity
        elif row.Type == 'BC':
            q = row.Quantity
        else:
            q = -row.Quantity

        p = s + q
        print(f_df1)
        print('Current position Size ' + str(s))
        print('Quantity to update '+ str(q))

        t = row.Type
        return t, p
    else:
        t = row.Type
        p = row.PositionSize
        return t, p

df1[['Type', 'PositionSize']] = df1.apply(Check_Type, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

print(df1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.apply()` you could add the value needed in your calculation into a new column.

```
# Reverse the sign of Quantity for non B rows. 
# Add new column with the starting Position.
# Sum them together.

df.loc[ df.Type != 'B', 'Quantity' ] *= -1
df['Pos'] = df.loc[0, 'Quantity']
df.Pos = df.Pos + df.Quantity

>>> df
       Date Ticker Type  Quantity  Pos
0  20200501   AAPL   SS      -200 -400
1  20200502   AAPL    B       150  -50
2  20200502   APPL    B       200    0
3  20200502   APPL    B        50 -150
4  20200502   AAPL    S      -100 -300
```

(First `Pos` is "wrong" but you can replace it if needed)

```
# Change the type on `B` rows with a negative Pos

df.loc[ (df.Type == 'B') & (df.Pos < 0), 'Type' ] = 'BC'

>>> df
       Date Ticker Type  Quantity  Pos
0  20200501   AAPL   SS      -200 -400
1  20200502   AAPL   BC       150  -50
2  20200502   APPL    B       200    0
3  20200502   APPL   BC        50 -150
4  20200502   AAPL    S      -100 -300
```

Put the quantities back to positive and delete the `Pos` column.

```
df.Quantity = df.Quantity.abs()
del df['Pos']

>>> df
       Date Ticker Type  Quantity
0  20200501   AAPL   SS       200
1  20200502   AAPL   BC       150
2  20200502   APPL    B       200
3  20200502   APPL   BC        50
4  20200502   AAPL    S       100
```

Comment: Great thank you! verry nice and clear way to approach this issue. probably should learn more about using loc. in pandas.Thanks again!